# Issue in multidimentional array in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is this valid way to assign all the values of one 2D array to another 2D array?

```
matrix1=matrix2;
```

They both are `mXn` dimension.

Comment: What's expected result from this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use **[`Array.Copy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

```
Array.Copy(sourceArray, targetArray);
```